# Java array split string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have an array with each element containing first and second names,

```
 eg array[0] = bob dylan
    array[1] = johny cash
```

I want to take those names, split them, and assign the first name to element[0] of a new array, and the surname to element[1] of the new array,

```
  eg newArray[0] = bob
     newArray[1] = dylon
     newArray[2] = johny
     newArray[3] = cash
```

Here's where I'm at so far:

```
  String name;
  for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
        System.out.println( "Enter the singers First name and Surname:" );
        name = s.nextLine();
        array[ i ] = name;
    }
```

I've got both arrays ready but i'm unsure whether I need to take the array elements and assign them to a string 1 by 1, then split them and put them in a new array, or perhaps theres a way to look at each element of a string[] and split them and assign to a new array without needing to use seperate strings. Many Thanks

Comment: You could have a look at the Javadoc for the `String` class, in particular the `split` method, and also the Javadoc for the `List` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `String.split()` and the Java Collections package to deal with the unknown array size.

```
String[] names = new String[] {"bob dylan", "johny cash"};

List<String> splitNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (String name : names) {
    splitNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(name.split(" ")));
}
```

From here, you can iterate through each name in your `String` array and split it based on a regex, such as a space. You can then add the result to your `List` of `Strings` which would contain:

```
"bob", "dylan", "johny", "cash"
```

By using Collections, you do not need to know the size of your names `String` array, and you can handle cases where a name does not have multiple parts.

If you need to convert the `List` back to an array:

```
String[] splitNamesArray = splitNames.toArray(new String[splitNames.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [StringUtils.join](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String%29) method in apache common lang.

```
String[] newArray = StringUtils.join(array," ").split("\\s+");
```